# CSS and JavaScript not centering after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hey all I am trying my best to get this animation correct. Seems it may be in the JavaScript but not sure.

[image]

The movie poster **should** load up in the center. Currently though its loading up all the way in the corner.

[image]

It should look like this when you click on a poster

[image]

Here is the [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/stealthrt/pen/ExyVrmE)!

```
var $play = $('.play'),
$detail   = $('.detail'),
$movie    = $('.movie', $detail),
$close    = $('.close');

$('.movies .movie').click(function(){
  $movie.html($(this).html());
  $play.appendTo($movie);
  $poster = $('.poster', this).addClass('active');

    console.log("===debug===============");
    console.log("top: " + $poster.position().top);
    console.log("left: " + $poster.position().left);
    console.log("width: " + $poster.width());
    console.log("height: " + $poster.height());
    
  $('.poster', $detail).css({
    top: $poster.position().top,
    left: $poster.position().left,
    width: $poster.width(),
    height: $poster.height()
  }).data({
    top: $poster.position().top,
    left: $poster.position().left,
    width: $poster.width(),
    height: $poster.height()
  })

  $detail.show();

  $('.poster', $detail).delay(10).queue(function(next) {
    $detail.addClass('ready');
    next();
  }).delay(100).queue(function(next){
    $(this).css({
      top: '-10%',
      left: '-6%',
      width: 266,
      height: 400
    });
    next();
  })
})

function close(){
  console.log('asd');
  $p = $('.detail .poster');
  console.log($p)
  $p.css({
    top: $p.data('top'),
    left: $p.data('left'),
    width: $p.data('width'),
    height: $p.data('height'),
  })
  $detail.removeClass('ready').delay(500).queue(function(next){
    $(this).hide();
    $poster.removeClass('active');
    next();
  });
}

$('body').click(function(e){
  $p = $(e.target).parents();
  
  if ($p.is('.app')){
    return false;
  } else {
    close();
  }
})
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Top and Left syntax expect more than just a number for length. *Sets the `top` edge position in px, cm, etc. Negative values are allowed.* See more: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: what part of your code is actually supposed to center it, I see you doing something like `top: '-10%', width: '-6%'` but without any context I wouldn't expect that to center it

Comment: I'd suggest you to use flex and classes instead of setting styles in JS

Comment: This is where the code is forcing the clicked image to move to the top left... `$('.poster', $detail).delay(10).queue(function(next) { $detail.addClass('ready'); next(); }).delay(100).queue(function(next){ $(this).css({ top: '-10%', left: '-6%', width: 266,  height: 400 });`

Answer (score 0):

change the position property in css file from absolute to relative as below.

```
.detail .poster { 
  position: relative;
......
...
}
```

Comment: Doing that makes it not go back into the original spot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Change Position of poster to relative and than use display and float accordingly.
```

please find updated

[codepan](https://codepen.io/kushalraid/pen/jOrbdem)

Comment: That seems really jumpy compaired to the original, smooth back and forth motion?